# How to convert Multiple png or Jpeg images into one nifti image by python3?

Tags: python-3.x, nifti, medical-imaging

I have 191 different png images.

How can I convert them into one 3d nifti image?

Comment: What have you tried? Can you find an applicable question on SO?

Comment: @Naemul please explain more, in many cases you don't have to pack the images into nifti ! also you need the header and the affine transformation matrix which may change after prediction.

Comment: @Belal I have the information (Metafile) as well as the affine matrix from the original nifti image from where I get 191 png images , after some analysis I want to convert them into nifti again with all the same information.

Comment: @Naemul please see my answer here [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60495310/)

Answer (score 4):

Here's a SimpleITK python script that can read in a stack of PNG images and output a 3d Nifti image:

```
import SimpleITK as sitk
import glob

file_names = glob.glob('*.png')
reader = sitk.ImageSeriesReader()
reader.SetFileNames(file_names)
vol = reader.Execute()
sitk.WriteImage(vol, 'volume.nii.gz')
```

The script assumes that the `glob` gets the file names in the proper order.  Also the 3-d volume created will have uniform spacing in X, Y, and Z.  If the Z spacing is not the same as X and Y, you can call `vol.SetSpacing` with whatever the spacing values should be.